# How do I alculate 2 means per subject differentiated by a variable in R

Tags: r, mean

This is my first question on stack noverflow. I have tried some reasearch, but I am not getting there. I am trying to calculate two differents means per subjet which are differentiated by a variable in R.
I created this example data set:

```
airquality <- data.frame(subject = c("CityA", "CityA","CityA","CityA", "CityA", "CityA", "CityA", "CityA",
                                  "CityB","CityB","CityB", "CityB", "CityB", "CityB", "CityB", "CityB",
                                  "CityC", "CityC", "CityC", "CityC", "CityC", "CityC", "CityC", "CityC"),
                         code = c("AA_high", "BB_high", "AA_low", "BB_low", "AB_high", "AB_low", "BA_high", "BA_low",
                                  "AA_high", "BB_high", "AA_low", "BB_low", "AB_high", "AB_low", "BA_high", "BA_low",
                                  "AA_high", "BB_high", "AA_low", "BB_low", "AB_high", "AB_low", "BA_high", "BA_low"),
                         measure = c("2", "6", "5", "3", "5", "5", "4", "6",
                                   "7", "8", "6", "7", "4", "12", "9", "7",
                                   "8", "12", "11", "9", "15", "11", "10", "16"))
print(airquality)
```

The aim is to have 2 means per subject: The first mean is the mean of all the measures which codes start with "AA" or "BB".
The second mean per subject should be the mean of the measures of all the codes which start with "AB" or "BA".

I started with this:

```
df1 <- filter(airquality, substr(code, 1, 2) == "AA" | substr(code, 1,2) == "BB") 
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(mean_AABB = mean(measure))
View(df1)

df2 <- filter(airquality, substr(code, 1, 2) == "AB" | substr(code, 1,2) == "BA") 
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(mean_ABBA = mean(measure))
View(df2)
```

But this doesn't seem to work and I need to have columns added to the dataframe, so I can do more calculations with the means.
So the next step would be to add those type of means to the dataframe.

I am very grateful for help!
Thanks very much,
Maike

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
library(dplyr)

airquality |>
  group_by(first_two_equal = substr(code, 1, 1) == substr(code, 2, 2)) |>
  mutate(measure = as.numeric(measure), ## !
         mean = mean(measure)
         )
```

(mind that `measure` of your example data is mode "character" so you'll need to convert it to "numeric")

**edit**
For extended grouping, include the additional factors in the `group_by` like so:

```
airquality |>
  group_by(subject, 
           first_two_equal = substr(code, 1, 1) == substr(code, 2, 2)
           ) |>
  mutate(measure = as.numeric(measure), ## !
         mean = mean(measure)
         )
```

output:

```
+ # A tibble: 24 x 5
# Groups:   subject, first_two_equal [6]
   subject code    measure first_two_equal  mean
   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl> <lgl>           <dbl>
 1 CityA   AA_high       2 TRUE                4
 2 CityA   BB_high       6 TRUE                4
 3 CityA   AA_low        5 TRUE                4
 4 CityA   BB_low        3 TRUE                4
 5 CityA   AB_high       5 FALSE               5
 6 CityA   AB_low        5 FALSE               5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your idea does not work fully for me, because this way, I only have 2 means (1 for AA/BB and 1 for AB/BA) for all the subjects. However, I need 2 means **per subject**. In the end I need every subject to have its AA/BB and AB/BA mean score. So I need to be able to grup the data by subject **and** by code. Do you have an idea for that?